# Pandas Dataframe Combinations of Every Two Rows

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I am implementing a clustering algorithm which requires the calculation of the distance between every pair of data points, where each data point is stored as a row in a pd.Dataframe. The total calculation grow in order of O(n^2) which I have to be cautious to do this efficiently.

What is an efficient way of doing what I want?

say I have 4 data points in a dataframe:

```
#<inputtable tin>
Id    Label 
0     Michael
1     Jim
2     Pam
3     Dwight
```

And I need to run a customized function `similar(x,y)` to calculate the discount between every two points Combination(2,4) ~ 6 and my output should be like:

```
#<outputtable tout>
Source_Id    Source_Label    To_Id    To_Label    distance 
0            Michael         1        Jim         f('Michael', 'Jim')
0            Michael         2        Pam         f('Michael', 'Pam')
0            Michael         3        Dwight      f('Michael', 'Dwight')
1            Jim             2        Pam         f('Jim', 'Pam')
1            Jim             3        Dwight      f('Jim', 'Dwight')
2            Pam             3        Dwight      f('Pam', 'Dwight')
```

What I have done:

I tried to use pd.merge to generate the cartesian product for the table

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[0, 'Michael'], [1, 'Jim'], [2, 'Pam'], [3, 'Dwight']], columns=['Id', 'Label'])
data['tmp'] = 1
result = pd.merge(data, data, left_on='tmp', right_on='tmp')
result = result[result['Id_x'] != result['Id_y']]
print result
```

however, this looks really like a hack around merge, I also tried itertools with combination which does not work that well with Pandas.

Anyone knows a more efficient way doing this sort of "clustering work" with a customized similar distance function? I am also planning to analyze that in Gephi which I do not know if there is a better solution in general.

Answer (score 1):

**FIRSTLY**
I can't solve the *O(n^2)* problem.

**`itertools.combination`**

```
from itertools import combinations

labels = df.Label.values.tolist()

f = lambda x, y: x + y

pd.Series({k: f(*k) for k in combinations(labels, 2)})
```

**`np.triu_indices`**

```
labels = df.Label.values

f = lambda x, y: x + y

i, j = np.triu_indices(labels.size, 1)

combs = list(zip(labels[i], labels[j]))

pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combs).to_series().apply(lambda t: f(*t))
```